# PDO::lastInsertID sometimes doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, last-insert-id

Something strange is happening with my pdo connection when I get the lastInsertId(): in 90% times it work well, but in 10% of the cases it returns 0 (I don't know if is really 0 or FALSE).
But in 100% of cases my records are successfully inserted.

Here is my code:

```
function execute_insert($sql, $values) {
    try {
        $dbConnection = new PDO('mysql:dbname=mydb;host=localhost;charset=utf8', 'username', 'mypass');

        $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $dbConnection->beginTransaction();
        $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->execute($values);

        $i = $dbConnection->lastInsertId();

        $dbConnection->commit();
        return $i;

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "erro :S - " . $e->getMessage();
        die();
    }
}


//blablabla

$sql = "INSERT INTO ai_pessoas(nome, tipo, cpf, orgao_emissor_id,
    rg_uf, rg, telefone1, telefone2, celular1, cidade_id, cep, endereco,
    numero,complemento,bairro, email_principal, email_secundario, email_principal_confirmado,
    dt_nascimento, oferta_id) "; 

$sql .= "VALUES(:nome,1,:cpf,:orgaorg,:ufrg,:rg,:telefone,:outroTelefone,:celular,:cidade,:cep,:endereco,:numero,:complemento,:bairro,:email,:emailAlternativo,FALSE,:datanasc,:idOfertaAtual);";

$idPessoa = execute_insert($sql,
        array(
            ':nome' => $nome,
            ':cpf' => $cpf,
            ':orgaorg' => $orgaorg,
            ':ufrg' => $ufrg,
            ':rg' => $rg,
            ':telefone' => $telefone,
            ':outroTelefone' => $outroTelefone,
            ':celular' => $celular,
            ':cidade' => $cidade,
            ':cep' => $cep,
            ':endereco' => $endereco,
            ':numero' => $numero,
            ':complemento' => $complemento,
            ':bairro' => $bairro,
            ':email' => $email,
            ':emailAlternativo' => $emailAlternativo,
            ':datanasc' => $datanasc,
            ':idOfertaAtual' => $idOfertaAtual
));

if ($idPessoa > 0){
   //sometimes enters here, sometimes not
}
```

My records are aways inserted, but the "if ($idPessoa > 0)" sometimes doest work meaning that $idPessoa is 0 or FALSE.

Any clue?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can try [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) for this purpose.

P.S. Your function connects every time.

P.P.S. Also i see that you do not handle errors and rollback. I think that in your 10% insert are failed. Explore about double calling this function because you have UNIQUE index on some field. And add check [result of execute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#refsect1-pdostatement.execute-returnvalues) and [errorInfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php).

Comment: Hello, thanks for you answer. I'll try this and if it works  I'll let you know.

Comment: PS: It's a simple web page, so I use this connection only in 2 places, in distinct occasions, but I'll fix it in future. PPS: I believe that isn't failing, because this script have more lines after the end of `if ($idPessoa > 0){...}` and they are executed. i.e.: the `die()` command never execute... (at least this code never raised any `PDOException`).